# Free software for mathematical modeling. Is R a good one?

Tags: r, math, modeling, mathematical-expressions

I am looking for a free software for mathematical modeling.

Here is a list of things I might be willing to achieve with this software: *Integrating functions, solving differential equations, graph theory, analyzing infinite series, local stability analysis, Taylor series, get eigenvectors, compute the long term behaviour of a system of equations, etc...*

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391224/free-online-mathematical-software) is a related SE post. I am surprised that nobody is suggesting R. I am currently a R user and already use R for graph theory. Therefore I would appreciate to use R also to make other mathematical modeling. Is R less efficient that Sage, SimPy, Mathematica and others for mathematical modeling? Why? Do you know a manual providing exaplanation for how to make mathematical modeling with R?

Thank you

Comment: R is not suggested in the linked SE post because Maple and Mathematica  are clearly [CASs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) while R is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like R is your first way to go. It does not make to good sense to compare R with any other tool in such a braod way you are asking for. R packages differ largely in efficiency, some are in fact C tools while others are written in the R language. As a start R can hardly be any wrong and is free.

Matlab might be a stable alternative, Julia is rising but still pre alpha.